# Largest girth of a graph of average degree k

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let G be a graph with $n \ge 3$ nodes and with average degree $3\le k\le n$.  What are the largest and smallest girth G can have?

Comment: I want to say that you should be able to reduce to the case when there’s $o(n)$ vertices of degree 2, by rearranging vertices (for example, you can show that if a vertex with degree at least 4 is incident to two cycles longer than the girth, containing distinct vertices of degree 2, then you can reduce the count of degree two vertices without decreasing girth). if you can formalize this claim, then I think it should basically reduce to maximizing the girth of a cubic graph, which is pretty open currently.

Comment: @ZachHunter aha but is there some reasonable lower bounds?

Comment: yes, there is a logarithmic lower bound. and I would guess that you can mimic the usual proof for the girth of graphs with mimimum degree 3 to get a logarithmic upper bound too.

Comment: Oh really that's pretty interesting, could you pass a reference to the logarithmic lower bound?  For me that may be enough

Comment: they are mentioned (with references) in the introduction of the recent preprint: https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.14638

Comment: @ZachHunter Thanks a lot for the reference.  I updated my question to let the average degree also vary.  Since your linked preprint answered a lot for me in the cubic graphs case.

Comment: What do you mean by "average degree"? Do you consider graphs that have vertices of different degrees (within the same graph)?

Comment: @WlodAA Yes exactly, I'm not requiring that they have the same number of edges at every vertex.

Comment: Thus, the average degree of $\ (V\ E)\ $ is simply $\ \frac{2\cdot|E|}{|V|}.$ (?) #### Are the shortest S, and the longest L absolute S(n) and L(n), across all averages $\ k\ge 3 $ or are they functions w.r. to k too: S(k n) and L(k n)? Or both? #### Then, S(n)=3 attained for $\ k=n-1$ (average degree k must be $k\le n-1$).

Comment: @WlodAA Exactly.  Sorry what is $S(n)$ and $L(n)$?  Are they the shortest and longest non-trivial cycles?

Comment: $L(n)\ $ and $\ S(n)\ $ are the shortests and the longest GIRTHs among all n-vertex graphs ($|V|=n$).

Comment: Ah okay exactly.  Then, I'm looking for a good lower-bound on $L(n,k)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find your answer in the paper:

**Generalized Girth Problems in Graphs and Hypergraphs**

By Uriel Feige and Tal Wagner.

Let $A_2(n,k)$ denotes the optimal upper bound for girth of graphs with $n$ nodes and average degree $k$. So, it is proved that we have
$$A_2(n,k)=\Theta(\log_{k-1}(n))$$ and it is best possible. Also, finding the best possible constant $c$ of the $log^{n}_{k-1}$ is an open problem and the best upper bound is $c\leq 2$ and the best lower bound is $c\geq 4/3$.

By Erdos work we have:
$$A_2(n,k)\leq 4n/k$$.

For some good results you can see the girth of Tanner graphs of Low-density parity check codes and the conditions for having special girth in bipartite graphs.

Comment: sorry what is l and d?  (Could you add a bit more detail svp)

Comment: OK, when we set $l=2$ in the mentioned paper, we get the usual Girth definition as you want. The parameter $k$ in your question is equivalent to $d$ parameter in the paper.  Also, there is a good relation between your question and low density parity check codes and the Girth of Tanner graphs.

Comment: Thanks; one question.  Do you know why the paper is not published yet (since it is not so recent).

Comment: @AIM no I do not know.

Comment: ah but does the paper also provide *lower bounds* on $A_2(n,k)$?